# ¿Cómo empaquetar correctamente Electron + Angular-cli 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, angular-cli, electron-build

Mi pregunta es porque llevo mucho tiempo viendo cómo hacerlo y las primeras veces llegó a funcionar pero útimamente he tenido muchos problemas.

He visto varios Blogs sobre como enlazar Electron con Angular pero siempre me sucede que tengo errores con el main.js en el loadURL

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: 'frontend',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });


    mainWindow.maximize();
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    mainWindow.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
            protocol: "file:",
            slashes: true
        })
    );

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
})
```

Ya hice los cambios que comúnmente suelen decir los videos y [páginas](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-electron) sobre esto como

Editando el package.json con `"main": "main.js",`

Poner el punto en `<base href="./">`

En el angular.json projects>appName>architect>build>options>outputPath cambiarlo por `"outputPath": "dist",` sin el título del proyecto

Todo lo anterior funciona hasta el momento de empaquetarlo

Para lo que varios mencionan usar `"electron-packager": "^14.2.1",`

Desde un comando mas simple como

```
"packager ": "electron-packager . --platform=win32 --out dist/ --overwrite"
```

Donde antes que nada, me genera un error con `pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),` porque lo ubica en otro lado y tengo que cambiar dist/ por src/

Que genera el exe pero al momento de iniciar solo aparece la tag `<app-root></app-root>` sin los scripts de angular, ósea una página vacía

[image: Electron en blanco]

Y otros [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643270/angular-5-with-electron-packager) para crear el script de package.json como:

```
"electron-package": "ng build --prod && electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/node_modules --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src --overwrite"
```

o

```
"electron-package": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron-packager . --no-prune --ignore=/e2e --ignore=/src --overwrite"
```

Que estos últimos creo no genera el index.html :c

¿Alguien conoce un proceso Definitivo con Anglar-cli y Electron?

Comment: En estos casos pruebo con algún *boilerplate*. He usado [este](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron/blob/master/README.md) con anterioridad en Linux y va bastante bien. No se si aplica en tu caso o en tu distribución, pero vale la pena probarlo. Saludos

Comment: ¿Y solo copio el repositorio y hago lo que quiero por encima?

Comment: Exacto. Eso es un *boilerplate*, un punto de inicio.

Comment: Excelente. No me parece lo mejor, pero funciona